# ZF: Using setObjectKey in partialLoop for only specific partials

Tags: php, zend-framework, partials

I've figured out how to get models into partialLoops using the setObjectKey method of the PartialLoop helper. What I'm wondering if there is a way to specify that specific partial loops use the model key and other ones don't. Right now I think I have to do something like this:

```
// sets the object key for ALL partialLoops
$this->partialLoop()->setObjectKey("model");
// do the thing
echo $this->partialLoop("elements/recent-blog.phtml", $this->blogs);
// reset the object key so further partialLoops do NOT use the key
$this->partialLoop()->setObjectKey(null);
```

Any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion to NOT using setObjectKey() is plain wrong - provided code would certainly fail to work with array of objects. Straight from the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html):

> If your model is an object, you may
>   want to have it passed as an object to
>   the partial script, instead of
>   serializing it to an array of
>   variables. You can do this by setting
>   the 'objectKey' [..skip..]

So, if you don't want your objects to be serialized, you have to use setObjectKey(). Since parial and partialLoop helpers are both accessible from controller and view (as any other view helper), I tend to enable object key globally, and switch it of in particular loop (re-enabling at the loop end). Extra typing for sure, but seems to work well.

Comment: Yeah, coming back to this I ended up using setObjectKey and it worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be NOT using setObjectKey(). Why not just do this:

```
echo $this->partialLoop("elements/recent-blog.phtml", array('model' => $this->blogs));
```

It has the same effect as using setObjectKey(). In [this](http://blog.vandenbos.org/2009/10/20/zf-assigning-objects-to-partials/) article on my blog I explain more about this.

Comment: Interesting. For some reason I thought I wouldn't be able to access the magic database methods of a model class doing it like so. Thought I tested it, but I'll have to retry. Thanks.